# Why Sqlite Error: cannot create INSTEAD OF trigger on table?

Tags: database, triggers, sqlite

I try to create an instead-of trigger for an update on a table. The normal use of instead-of triggers are views but the Sqlite manual says that instead-of triggers are also valid for tables. But I get the error: *cannot create INSTEAD OF trigger on table*. And I am wondering why.

I use foreign keys:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

And I have two tables. An identifier table:

```
CREATE TABLE id
(
    id      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    created REAL    NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

And a table which references the identifiers:

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
    id        INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT (last_insert_rowid()) REFERENCES id,
    login     TEXT,
    password  TEXT,
    firstname TEXT,
    lastname  TEXT,
    email     TEXT,
    created   REAL  NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, created)
);
```

Insert works fine:

```
INSERT INTO id DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO person (login) VALUES ('root');
SELECT * FROM person;
1|root|||||2012-02-28 18:03:45
```

Now I want to define the following trigger, which converts an update into an insert:

```
CREATE TRIGGER person_update INSTEAD OF UPDATE OF login, password, firstname, lastname, email ON person
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO person (login, password, firstname, lastname, email)
    VALUES (new.login, new.password, new.firstname, new.lastname, new.email);
END;
```

But it fails with the above error and I do not understand why.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I tried going through [the source code](http://www2.sqlite.org/cgi/src/artifact/ee7e178fb9188f44b532cebd449a7c1df90fb684) (search for "cannot create INSTEAD OF") and despite reading your link in the comment where the create trigger statement is outlined in great detail, I would say that triggers with `INSTEAD OF` are only for views and cannot be used with tables.

Comment: Yes, this is the right answer. INSTEAD OF triggers are just for views.

Comment: Triggers may be created on views, as well as ordinary tables, by     specifying INSTEAD OF in the CREATE TRIGGER statement.

Comment: @NoobSaibot The "bullshit" is written in the official Sqlite documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping that this is just a typo in the post, but your `create` statement should read:

```
INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON
```

you've typed:

```
INSTEAD OF UPDATE OF
```

Comment: No this is wrong. The syntax is INSTEAD OF UPDATE OF column-name ON table-name. See here: http://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Answer (score 0):

Just create a view `person_view as select * from person` and point your trigger to it.